# How to display chats related to each friend in the friendlist getting from socket in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Iam working on chat application.I have completed for displaying chat messages in the way sending messages are displayed on right side and receiving messages on left side.It is working well.But my problem is when I click another friend name,previous chat related to previous friend is displaying along with new friend chat messages.How can I solve this problem.Iam using same array for getting old chats and for receiving messages also.
Here is my code:

```js
var grp = angular.module("grpApp", [])

.config(function ($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{|');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('|}');
})
   .controller("grpCtrl", function ($scope, $state, $http, ) {
    $scope.msgFrom = $state.params.username;
    $scope.userId = $state.params.userid;
    $scope.isVisible = true;
    $scope.room = true;
    console.log("sajs" + $scope.msgFrom);
    console.log("ashgxsh" + $scope.userId);
    document.getElementById("frndName").innerHTML = "Group";
    $scope.msgdata = [];
    $scope.friendsList = [];
    $scope.groupList = [];
    $scope.arrData = [];
    $scope.recData;
    $scope.recArr = [];
    $scope.setroom;
    //Enter Option
    document.getElementById("myMsg").addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            document.getElementById("sendBtn").click();
        }
    });

//socket............................................................................................................

    var socket = io('http://colourssoftware.com:3000/chat');
    var username = $scope.msgFrom;
    var noChat = 0; //setting 0 if all chats histroy is not loaded. 1 if all chats loaded.
    var msgCount = 0; //counting total number of messages displayed.
    var oldInitDone = 0; //it is 0 when old-chats-init is not executed and 1 if executed.
    var roomId; //variable for setting room.
    var toUser;

    //passing data on connection.
    socket.on('connect', function () {
        socket.emit('set-user-data', $scope.msgFrom);
        console.log("emitted" + $scope.msgFrom);
    }); //end of connect event.

    //receiving onlineStack.
    socket.on('onlineStack', function (stack) {
        console.log("data" + JSON.stringify(stack));
        $('#list').empty();
        $('#list').append($('<li>').append($('<span id="ubtn" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-sm"></span>').text("Group").css({
            "font-size": "15px",
            //            "border-radius": "2em"
        })));
        var totalOnline = 0;
        for (var user in stack) {
            //setting txt1. shows users button.
            if (user != $scope.msgFrom) {
                //                var txt1 = $('<span style="display:none" ></span>').text(user).css({
                //                    "font-size": "19px"
                //
                //                });
                //            } else {
                var txt1 = $('<a  href="#" id="ubtn"> < /a>').text(user).css({
                    "font-size": "15px",
                    "text-decoration": "none"

                });

            }
            //setting txt2. shows online status.
            if (stack[user] == "Online") {
                if (user != $scope.msgFrom) {
                    var txt2 = $('<span></span>').text("*" + stack[user]).css({
                        "float": "right",
                        "color": "#009933",
                        "font-size": "15px"
                    });
                    totalOnline++;

                }
            } else {
                var txt2 = $('<span></span>').text(stack[user]).css({
                    "float": "right",
                    "color": "#a6a6a6",
                    "font-size": "15px"
                });

            }

            //listing all users.
            $('#list').append($('<li>').append(txt1, txt2));
            $('#totalOnline').text(totalOnline);
        } //end of for.
        $('#scrl1').scrollTop($('#scrl1').prop("scrollHeight"));

    }); //end of receiving onlineStack event.

    
    //on button click function.
    $(document).on("click", "#ubtn", function () {
        //empty messages.
        $('#messages').empty();
        $('#typing').text("");
        msgCount = 0;
        noChat = 0;
        oldInitDone = 0;

        //assigning friends name to whom messages will send,(in case of group its value is Group).
        toUser = $(this).text();
        console.log("touser:" + toUser);
        //showing and hiding relevant information.
        $('#frndName').text(toUser);
        $('#initMsg').hide();
        $('#chatForm').show(); //showing chat form.
        //        $('#sendBtn').hide();//hiding send button to prevent sending of empty messages.

        //assigning two names for room. which helps in one-to-one and also group chat.
        if (toUser == "Group") {
            var currentRoom = "Group-Group";
            var reverseRoom = "Group-Group";
        } else {
            var currentRoom = username + "-" + toUser;
            var reverseRoom = toUser + "-" + username;
        }

        //event to set room and join.
        socket.emit('set-room', {
            name1: currentRoom,
            name2: reverseRoom
        });
        console.log("room" + currentRoom + " " + reverseRoom);
    });
    //event for setting roomId.
    socket.on('set-room', function (room) {
        //empty messages.
        $('#messages').empty();
        $('#typing').text("");
        msgCount = 0;
        noChat = 0;
        oldInitDone = 0;
        //assigning room id to roomId variable. which helps in one-to-one and group chat.
        roomId = room;
        $scope.setroom = roomId;
        console.log("roomId : " + roomId);




        //event to get chat history on button click or as room is set.
        socket.emit('old-chats-init', {
            room: roomId,
            username: $scope.msgFrom,
            msgCount: msgCount
        });

    }); //end of set-room event.





    //on scroll load more old-chats.
    $('#scrl2').scroll(function () {

        if ($('#scrl2').scrollTop() == 0 && noChat == 0 && oldInitDone == 1) {
            $('#loading').show();
            socket.emit('old-chats', {
                room: roomId,
                username: username,
                msgCount: msgCount
            });
        }

    }); // end of scroll event.

    //listening old-chats event.
    socket.on('old-chats', function (data) {
        msgCount = 0;
        console.log("count" + JSON.stringify(data));
        $scope.merid;
//        if (data.msgTo != $scope.arrData.msgTo) {
            if (data.room == roomId) {
                oldInitDone = 1; //setting value to implies that old-chats first event is done.
                $('#messages').empty();
                $scope.arrData.length = 0;
                if (data.result.length != 0) {
                    console.log("length" + data.result.length);
                    $scope.room = false;

                    $('#noChat').hide(); //hiding no more chats message.
                    for (var i = data.result.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        $scope.merid = new Date(data.result[i].createdOn).getHours();
                        //                    data.result[i].createdOn = moment(data.createdOn).format("MMMM Do YYYY, hh:mm:ss a");
                        if ($scope.merid > 11) {
                            $scope.val = new Date(data.result[i].createdOn).toLocaleString() + "pm";
                            data.result[i].createdOn = $scope.val;
                        } else {
                            $scope.val = new Date(data.result[i].createdOn).toLocaleString() + "am";
                            data.result[i].createdOn = $scope.val;
                        }


                        $scope.arrData.push(data.result[i]);
                        msgCount++;

                    }
                    $scope.$apply();
                } else {
                    $scope.arrData.length = 0;
                    $('#noChat').show(); //displaying no more chats message.
                    noChat = 1; //to prevent unnecessary scroll event.
                }
                //hiding loading bar.
                $('#loading').hide();

                //setting scrollbar position while first 5 chats loads.
                if (msgCount <= 5) {
                    $('#scrl2').scrollTop($('#scrl2').prop("scrollHeight"));
                }

            }
        //end of outer if.

        //clearing chat history
        $scope.clearchat = function () {
            $http({
                url: 'http://colourssoftware.com:3000/Clear_Chat/' + roomId,
                method: 'DELETE',

            }).then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);

            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });

        }

    }); // end of listening old-chats event

    //receiving typing message.
    socket.on('typing', function (msg) {
        var setTime;
        //clearing previous setTimeout function.
        clearTimeout(setTime);
        //showing typing message.
        $('#typing').text(msg);
        //showing typing message only for few seconds.
        setTime = setTimeout(function () {
            $('#typing').text("");
        }, 3000);
    }); //end of typing event.

    //sending message.
    $('form').submit(function () {
        socket.emit('chat-msg', {
            msg: $('#myMsg').val(),
            msgTo: toUser,
            date: Date.now()
        });
        $('#myMsg').val("");
        //        $('#sendBtn').hide();
        return false;
    });

    //end of sending message.

    //receiving messages.
    socket.on('chat-msg', function (data) {
        //styling of chat message.
        console.log("received data" + JSON.stringify(data));
        var hrs = new Date(data.date).getHours;
        var dt = new Date(data.date);
        if (hrs > 11) {
            dt = dt.toLocaleString();
            data.date = dt + "pm";
        } else {
            dt = dt.toLocaleString();
            data.date = dt + "am";
        }
        $scope.arrData.push(data);
        $scope.$apply();
        msgCount++;
        console.log(msgCount);
        $('#typing').text("");
        $('#scrl2').scrollTop($('#scrl2').prop("scrollHeight"));
        //end of receiving messages.




    });
    //on disconnect event.
    //passing data on connection.
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        //showing and hiding relevant information.
        $('#list').empty();
        $('#messages').empty();
        $('#typing').text("");
        $('#frndName').text("Disconnected..");
        $('#loading').hide();
        $('#noChat').hide();
        $('#initMsg').show().text("...Please, Refresh Your Page...");
        $('#chatForm').hide();
        msgCount = 0;
        noChat = 0;
    }); //end of connect event.

    //end of function.


    //Functions................................................................................................

    //Getting friend requests:
    $scope.getFrndreq = function () {
        $http.get("http://colourssoftware.com:3000/Friend_Requests/" + $scope.msgFrom)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log("response", JSON.stringify(response));
                $scope.groupList = response.data;
                $scope.uname = $scope.groupList.username;
                console.log("username" + $scope.uname);

            }, function (response) {
                console.log("error" + response);
            });
    }
    $scope.getFrndreq();
    //Accept Friends.................................................................................
    $scope.accept = function (reqname, uname, userid, index) {
            $scope.reqName = reqname;
            $scope.userName = uname;
            $scope.userid = userid;

            //Requests Accepted(Friends List):
            var data = {
                "userId": $scope.userId,
                "requestname": $scope.reqName,
                "username": $scope.userName
            }
            var req = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://colourssoftware.com:3000/Accept_Requests',
                data: data
            }
            $http(req).then(function (response) {
                console.log("Frndslist" + JSON.stringify(response.data));
                $http({
                    url: 'http://colourssoftware.com:3000/Delete_Requests/' + $scope.userid,
                    method: 'DELETE',
                    data: {
                        id: $scope.userid
                    },

                }).then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    $scope.groupList.splice(index, 1);
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });

            }, function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
        }
        //Ignore Friends.............................................................................................
    $scope.ignore = function (userId, index) {
        $scope.userid = userId;
        console.log("ashgshd" + $scope.userid);
        if (confirm("Are you sure to ignore the request?")) {
            $http({
                url: 'http://colourssoftware.com:3000/Delete_Requests/' + $scope.userid,
                method: 'DELETE',
                data: {
                    id: $scope.userid
                },

            }).then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                $scope.groupList.splice(index, 1);
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        } else {

        }
    }

    //Getting Friends list accepted by user:
    $scope.acceptList = function () {
        //                $scope.requestname = reqname;
        $http.get("http://colourssoftware.com:3000/Accept_Requests/" + $scope.userId)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log("hi", JSON.stringify(response));
                $scope.friends = response.data;
                console.log("heloooo" + $scope.friends);

            });

        //Getting Friends list accepted by others:

        $http.get("http://colourssoftware.com:3000/Accepted_By_Others/" + $scope.msgFrom)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log("hi", JSON.stringify(response));
                $scope.friends = response.data;
                console.log("heloooo" + $scope.friends);

            });
    }

    //Getting requests list:
    $scope.addFrndFn = function () {
        $http.get("http://colourssoftware.com:3000/Users_List")
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log("hi", JSON.stringify(response));
                $scope.requests = response.data;
            }, function (response) {
                console.log("error" + response);
            });
    }

    $scope.addfrnd = function (reqname, id) {
        console.log("shgsgh" + reqname);
        var data = {
            userId: id,
            requestname: reqname,
            username: $scope.username
        }
        var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://colourssoftware.com:3000/Send_Requests',
            data: data
        }
        $http(req).then(function (response) {
            console.log("saghdha" + JSON.stringify(response.data));

            //Representing added friend requests
            $http.get("http://colourssoftware.com:3000/Users_List")
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log("hi", JSON.stringify(response));
                    $scope.requests = response.data;
                    //..........................................................................................
                    //Getting added list
                    $http.get("http://colourssoftware.com:3000/Get_Sent_Requests/" + $scope.username)
                        .then(function (response) {
                            $scope.addedList = response.data;
                            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.requests.length; i++) {
                                for (var j = 0; j < $scope.addedList.length; j++) {
                                    if ($scope.requests[i].username == $scope.addedList[j].requestname) {
                                        document.getElementById("changeValue").value = "Request Sent";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }, function (response) {
                            console.log("error" + response);
                        });
                    //..........................................................................................

                }, function (response) {
                    console.log("error" + response);
                });

        }, function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }




    //Delete requests:

    $scope.unfriend = function (userId) {
            $scope.userid = userId;
            console.log("ashgshd" + $scope.userid);
            $http({
                url: 'http://colourssoftware.com:3000/Delete_Friends/' + $scope.userid,
                method: 'DELETE',
                data: {
                    id: $scope.userid
                },

            }).then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
        //Logout Function...................................................................................
    $scope.logoutFn = function () {
        $http.get("http://colourssoftware.com:3000/user/Logout_User")
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log("hi" + response);
                $state.go("login");

            }, function (response) {
                console.log("error" + response);
            });

    }

});
```

```html
<!--        chat box using socket........................................................................-->
<main>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <input type="hidden" id="user" value="<%= user.username %>" />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4" style="border:1px solid #eee;height:645px;overflow:scroll">


                <div style="background-color:#eee;height:60px;">
                    <a><img src="images/image.jpg" class="img-circle" width="40" height="40" ng-click="imgFn()" ng-src="{|imageSource|}" style="margin-top:2%"></a>
                    <input type="file" accept="image/*" ng-model="imageSrc" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileNameChaged(this)" style="font-size:15px; position: absolute;" ng-hide="isVisible">
                    <span ng-bind="msgFrom" style="font-size:15px;color:black;margin-top:4%"></span>

                    <!--Modal...........................................................................-->
                    <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="float:right;margin-top:4.5%;margin-right:3%">
                        <a style="text-decoration:none;" ng-click="addFrndFn()">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="color:black"></span>
                        </a>
                        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">

                                <!-- Modal content-->
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title">Users List</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <span>Click add button to send friend requests</span>
                                        <ul class="list-group">
                                            <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="list in requests track by $index">
                                                <span ng-bind="list.username">
                            </span>
                                                <a href="#" class=" btn btn-primary" style="float:right;margin-left:2%;color:white;margin-top:-1.4%" ng-click="addfrnd(list.username,list.userId)" id="changeValue">Add</a>
                                            </li>

                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--..................................Modal close.............................................................-->

                    <div class="dropdown" style="float:right;margin-top:4.5%;margin-right:2%">
                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" style="text-decoration:none">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical" title="logout" style="color:black"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a ng-click="logoutFn()">Logout</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <h4 align="center"><b>Friend Requests</b></h4>
                <ul class="list-group" ng-repeat="frnd in groupList track by $index">
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <span ng-bind="frnd.username"> </span>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn btn-sm" style="width:20%;float:right;margin-top:-1.5%;margin-right:-2%" ng-click="ignore(frnd._id,$index)">Ignore</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn btn-sm" style="width:20%;float:right;margin-top:-1.5%;margin-right:2%" ng-click="accept(frnd.requestname,frnd.username,frnd._id,$index)">Accept</button>

                    </li>

                </ul>


                <h4 align="center"><b>Friends</b></h4>
                <div clid="scrl1">
                    <a id="list" style="text-decoration:none"></a>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class=".space"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 " style="border:1px solid #eee;background-image:url('images/paper2.jpg')">
                <div class="panel-warning">
                    <header style="background-color:#eee;height:60px">

                        <div class="panel-heading ">
                            <h4 id="frndName" style="color:black"><b></b></h4> <span id="typing" style="color:black"></span>
                            <a ng-click="clearchat()">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn" title="clear chat" style="float:right;margin-top:-5.5%;color:black"></span>
                            </a>


                        </div>
                    </header>
                    <div class="panel-body" id="scrl2" style="height:530px;overflow:scroll">
                        <p id="loading" align="center">Loading.....</p>
                        <p id="noChat" align="center">No More Chats To Display.....</p>
                        <p id="initMsg" align="center">!!...Click On User Or Group Button To Start Chat...!!</p>
                        <div class="chat" ng-hide="room">
                            <!--                            <ul id="messages" style="float:left"></ul>-->
                            <section class="module">
                                <ol class="discussion" ng-repeat="message in arrData track by $index">
                                    <li ng-class="message.msgFrom == msgFrom?'self':'other'">
                                        <div class="messages" ng-style="message.msgFrom == msgFrom?{'background-color':'#66B2FF','border-radius':'20px 20px 0px 20px'}:{'background-color':'#fff','border-radius':'20px 20px 20px 0px'}">
                                            <p class="paratext" id="messages" ng-style="message.msgFrom == msgFrom?{'background-color':'#66B2FF','color':'#fff'}:{'background-color':'#fff'}">
                                                <span id="uname" ng-bind="(message.msgFrom)+(' ')+(message.createdOn)"></span>
                                                <br><span id="userMsg" ng-bind="(message.msg)"></span>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ol>
                                <ol class="discussion" ng-repeat="umsg in arrData track by $index">
                                    <li ng-class="umsg.msgFrom == msgFrom?'self':'other'">
                                        <div class="messages" ng-style="umsg.msgFrom == msgFrom?{'background-color':'#66B2FF','border-radius':'20px 20px 0px 20px'}:{'background-color':'#fff','border-radius':'20px 20px 20px 0px'}">

                                            <p class="paratext" id="messages" ng-style="umsg.msgFrom == msgFrom?{'background-color':'#66B2FF','color':'#fff','float':'right'}:{'background-color':'#fff'}">
                                                <span id="uname" ng-bind="(umsg.msgFrom)+(' ')+(umsg.date)"></span>
                                                <br><span id="userMsg" ng-bind="(umsg.msg)"></span>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ol>

                            </section>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer input-group" style="width:102%;margin-left:-2%">

                        <form id="chatForm" action="" onsubmit="return false">
                            <textarea id="myMsg" ng-keyup="do_resize(this);" cols="20" rows="1" name="description_name" class="input-box-send  form-control" ng-model="message" autocomplete="off" style="width:80%;" placeholder="Write Message Here.." />
                            <button type="submit" id="sendBtn" class=" btn btn-primary " ng-disabled="!message" name="btn" style="font-size:13px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```